# Is it possible to create a persistent TCP/IP socket connection from a ASP.NET web application/server to a connected client computer?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, service, tcp, ip

As the title says: Is it possible to create a persistent TCP/IP socket connection from a ASP.NET web application/server to a connected client computer?

I know it is a general question, however if it is possible, where would you recommend i start reading?

Thanks

EDIT:

The connection does not have to be between a client web browser. It could be a desktop application. I am just trying to figure out if the connection could be made.

EDIT #2:

I do not necessarily have to use ASP.NET, however, I have experience programming in .NET. Should I instead be looking into a Server "Service"? Is a asp.net web-service and a "service" the same?

Comment: I don't think you can but I think now it would have to be a websocket. Not sure if ASP.NET supports it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need that?

In order to make direct TCP connection to a client host several conditions should be met. There should be no firewall block of incoming connection to the port you want to connect to.

Client host should have accessible address (public IP). Usually client hosts are behind NAT so to open the connection some kind of [tcp-hole-punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching) should be used.

In the context of web application I would use some sort of [Comet protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) to emulate connecting to the client. See also [push technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have an application that will require me to make direct persistent 2-way TCP connections to a device. I am creating a proof of concept by first creating a connection to a client on a PC.

Answer (score 1):

`Websockets` is a spec in HTML5 that solves this issue. Have a look at the spec here:

http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/

Comment: The connection does not have to be between a client web browser. It could be a desktop application. I am just trying to figure out if the connection could be made.